# How to put a shipping scenario in Shopify that I have described in description?

Tags: liquid, cart, checkout, discount

I want to put the following conditions in my Shopify Store:

Suppose I have two products x and y.

- If I put x in cart shipping rates will be applied to it.
- If I put x and y in cart shipping will be free for both products.
- If I put y in cart shipping will be free.

If it is possible through liquid coding, then kindly guide me.

Comment: So... you're rule is just "if y is in the cart, shipping is free"?

Comment: @JamesZ ....yeah you got the point!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a **FREE** delivery option based on weight for orders of minimum **100kg** or whichever unreachable weight that would work with other products in your store.
2. Set the weight specified in the previous step to your **Y** product.